# mongodb: use inner property after ifNull

Tags: mongodb

I have the next documents in my MongoDB collection:

```
{ "current": { "foo": "bar" } } 
{ "new": { "foo": "baz" } }
```

I want to aggregate "foo" fields, which means after aggregation I should see:

```
{"foo": "bar"}, {"foo": "baz"}
```

but when I do an aggregation:

```
{
    "foo": {
      "current": {
         $ifNull: ["$current.foo", "$new.foo"]
      }
    } 
}
```

I get:

```
{ "foo" : { "current" : "bar" } } 
{ "foo" : { "current" : "baz" } }
```

Does mongo have any way to use get inner values?

Comment: just need to change the name of projection field from `current` to `foo`, like `"foo": { $ifNull: ["$current.foo", "$new.foo"] }`.

Comment: oh many thanks, so easy :)